# What is the meaning of source bin/activate in command prompt?

Tags: django

I am newbie of django , I  have installed django in a given folder "Dev->django"  but I am not able to start django. When I run a command `source bin/activate` output will be like `(django) akriti@akriti:~/Dev/django$`
what is the meaning of `(django)`  here?

Answer (score 1):

It's the name of your virtual environment. In order to incapsulate installed packages and prevent from conflicts between different version packages for different projects it's convenient to use Virtual Environment. You can read more [there](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).